# Equations involving arithmetic functions of primorials

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, factorization, divisors-multiples

Let $\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ the sum of divisors, $\varphi(n)$ the Euler's totient function and we denote the primorial $\prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ as $N_n$, where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime number. For integers $1\leq z<n$ and $m\geq 1$, and $a\geq 0$ I've consider if it is possible to find the solutions of some cases of the following equations of next problems.

**Problem 1.** Solve for positive integers $1\leq z,n, m$ and $a\geq 0$ 
$$\sigma\left(\frac{N_n}{N_z}\right)=2^aN_m\tag{1}$$
where also is required the condition $z<n$.

**Problem 2.** Solve for positive integers $1\leq z,n, m$ and $a\geq 0$
$$\varphi\left(\frac{N_n}{N_z}\right)=2^aN_m\tag{2}$$
where also is required the condition $z<n$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to make a remarkable progress in studying the solutions  of Problem 1? Is it possible to make a remarkable progress in studying the solutions  of Problem 2? **Many thanks.**

I denote the solutions as $(n,z,m;a)$ or $(n,z,m)$ for a given integer $a$, and from th context we know if it are solutions of the corresponding problem.   Below I add the cases for wich I've calculated some solutions using a Pari/GP program, over the segments of integers $1\leq z,n,m\leq 100$.

Here I add a claim for which I did an easy draft for its proof.

**Claim.** The equation $\varphi\left(\frac{N_n}{N_z}\right)=2^aN_m$  implies $n-z\leq a+1$ (the identity holds for the case $a=0$). Similarly we've a claim  for the other Problem 1. Further we know that the Euler's totient function and the sum of divisors function are multiplicative functions, and each (odd) prime number $p$ of the form $4\lambda+1$ contributes as $\sigma(p)\equiv2\text{ mod }4$ and $\varphi(p)\equiv 0\text{ mod }4$.

**Some solutions for Problem 1.** This is a summary of the solutions that I know for Problem 1, when $1\leq z,n,m\leq 100$ and $z<n$:

- For the case $a=0$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(3,2,2)$ and $(10,9,3)$.
- For the case $a=1$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(2,1,1)$,$(5,4,2)$,$(17,16,3)$ and $(81,80,4)$.
- For the case $a=2$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(3,1,2)$, $(4,3,1)$ and $(9,8,2)$.
- For the case $a=3$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(4,2,2)$, $(15,14,2)$ and $(52,51,3)$.

**Some solutions for Problem 2.** This is a summary of the solutions that I know for Problem 2, when $1\leq z,n,m\leq 100$ and $z<n$:

- For the case $a=0$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(2,1,1)$,$(4,3,2)$,$(11,10,3)$ and $(47,46,4)$.
- For the case $a=1$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(3,2,1)$, $(5,3,3)$,$(6,5,2)$,$(18,17,3)$,$(20,18,5)$ and $(82,81,4)$.
- For the case $a=2$ the solutions $(n,z,m)=(3,1,1)$, $(4,2,2)$,$(6,4,3)$ and $(11,9,4)$.
- For the case $a=3$ the solutions are $(n,z,m)=(4,1,2)$,$(5,2,3)$,$(7,6,1)$,$(11,8,5)$, $(14,12,4)$ and $(53,52,3)$.

Comment: For large values of our parameters, our integers in $(n,z,m;a)$,  I evoke that maybe my Claim can be improved by counting how many primes there are of the form $4\lambda+1$ in comparison with the size of $a$.

Comment: I was inspired in Florian Luca, *Equations Involving Arithmetic Functions of Factorials*, Divulgaciones Matemáticas Vol 8. No. 1 (2000).

Answer (score 3):

First we should compute the left side of the first equation:
$$\begin{array}{rcl} \displaystyle\sigma\left(\frac{N_n}{N_z}\right) & = & \displaystyle\sigma\left( \prod_{z < k \leq n}p_k \right) \\ \\  & = & \displaystyle\prod_{z < k \leq n}\dfrac{p_k^2-1}{p_k-1} \\ \\  & = & \displaystyle\prod_{z < k \leq n}(p_k+1) \end{array}$$
Then **problem 1** is solving:
$$\displaystyle\prod_{z < k \leq n}(p_k+1) = 2^a N_m$$
The reason why this equation is hard is the case $p_k+1=2^b$, then $p_k$ is **Mersenne prime**, and we don't know if the set of Mersenne's primes has infinite cardinality or not.

Your **problem2** is solving:
$$\varphi\left(\frac{N_n}{N_z}\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{z < k \leq n}(p_k-1)=2^aN_m$$

Same of **problem 1**:

If $p_k-1=2^b$ , then $p_k$ is **Fermat prime number** and we don't know if the set of Fermat's prime numbers has infinite cardinality or not.

Comment: Many thanks for your great contribution.

Comment: And your discussion for **Problem 1** also works for the equation $$\psi\left(\frac{N_n}{N_z}\right)=2^aN_m,$$ that is a different problem, a problem that involves the Dedekind psi function $\psi(l)$. Many thanks for you great answer again.